# QPersistentModelIndex updates wrong

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I'm trying to create a proxy model for my tree model, but for the sake of simplicity I decided to create proxy for a small table model firstly. Table model consists of 1 column and a few rows; the data stored in QStringList.

Proxy model stores mapping of source indices to proxy indices and vice versa in a pair of lists (which I asssume to use later in proxy for tree model, replacing lists with hash-tables):

```
QList<QPersistentModelIndex> m_sourceToProxyMap;
QList<QPersistentModelIndex> m_proxyToSourceMap;
```

I reimplemented proxy's `setSourceModel()` method to populate proxy mappings like so:

```
QAbstractProxyModel::setSourceModel(sourceModel);
for (int i = 0; i < sourceModel->rowCount({}); ++i) {
    auto sourceIndex = sourceModel->index(i, 0, {});
    auto proxyIndex = createIndex(i, 0, sourceIndex.internalPointer());
    m_sourceToProxyMap.append(proxyIndex);
    m_proxyToSourceMap.append(sourceIndex);
}
```

After proxy model was populated mappings contain following indices (I think it's correct result):

```
QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,ProxyTableModel(0x1e92930)) QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,TableModel(0x1feacf0))
QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,ProxyTableModel(0x1e92930)) QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,TableModel(0x1feacf0))
```

After inserting one row into source model at line 1 proxy model has wrong indices for changed rows:

```
QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,ProxyTableModel(0x1741e40)) QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,TableModel(0x19411b0))
QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,ProxyTableModel(0x1741e40)) QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,TableModel(0x19411b0))
QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,ProxyTableModel(0x1741e40)) QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,TableModel(0x19411b0))
```

Here is the proxy' slot that is connected to source model's `rowsInserted()` signal:

```
void ProxyTableModel::onSourceRowsInserted(const QModelIndex& sourceParent, int first, int last)
{
    beginInsertRows({}, first, last);
    auto sourceIndex = sourceModel()->index(first, 0, sourceParent);
    auto proxyIndex = createIndex(first, 0, sourceIndex.internalPointer());
    m_sourceToProxyMap.insert(first, proxyIndex);
    m_proxyToSourceMap.insert(first, sourceIndex);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

How to fix that? (Without populating proxy model completely from scratch at each insertion)

UPDATE: I think I got something. After new persistent index was created and inserted into mapping the `endInsertRows()` method updates indices (including new one), so the temporary workaround is to shift methods like so:

```
oid ProxyTableModel::onSourceRowsInserted(const QModelIndex& sourceParent, int first, int last)
{
    beginInsertRows({}, first, last);
    endInsertRows();
    auto sourceIndex = sourceModel()->index(first, 0, sourceParent);
    auto proxyIndex = createIndex(first, 0, sourceIndex.internalPointer());
    m_sourceToProxyMap.insert(first, proxyIndex);
    m_proxyToSourceMap.insert(first, sourceIndex);
}
```

Comment: If the proxy doesn't reorder the items, there's no need to use persistent indices at all, since you don't need to store any indices. You only need to appropriately react to the items being added/removed/moved in the source model.

Comment: It's about table model. But I intend to use it in tree model with flatten  proxy.